# JSON Schema object with primitive type or $ref type?

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have a schema in which a particular property (`child`) can be either a `string` or it can be an object I already have defined (`ChildClass`). I'm having a hard time defining this in the schema, however:

```
{
  definitions": {
    "ChildClass": { ... },
    "ParentClass": {
      "description": "The parent object",
      "type": [ "object" ],
      "properties": {
        "child": {
          "anyOf": [
            { "$ref": "#/definitions/ChildClass" },
            "string"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can use either the `"string"` definition *or* my referenced definition, but not both together (with `anyOf`). What's the appropriate syntax to allow the schema to understand that either one of these is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `anyOf` keyword requires schemas as its items.  `"string"` is not in itself a schema.  Try using

```
{"type": "string"}
```

inside the `anyOf` alongside your  `ChildClass` reference.

Comment: That did it! I set it to `"child": { "oneOf": [ { "$ref": "#/definitions/ChildClass" }, { "type": "string" } ] }`, and both types are accepted.